# How to get the names and ids of test cases that are under the Tested By section of a user story in tfs

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs

Tested BY(19)

Under tested by there are 19 test cases.

If the id of the user story is given how to get these test cases.

If (Link link is Related) returns all the links.

How to get just the test cases.

Any help would be appreciated. I just started working with tfs using c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [TFS REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-5.0) to get the information you need, the `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward` relation is the TestedBy link type. The API is as below:

```
GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=Relations&api-version=5.0-preview.3
```

The following screenshot is the response of the REST API:

[image]

Here is a sample with client library to get test case ids from the User Story for your reference:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;

namespace GetWorkItemFullyExpanded
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetWorkItemFullyExpanded();
        }

        public static WorkItem GetWorkItemFullyExpanded()
        {
            int id = xx;

            var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials();
            var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"https://xxxx.visualstudio.com"), myCredentials);
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            WorkItem workitem = workItemTrackingClient.GetWorkItemAsync(id, expand: WorkItemExpand.Relations).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(workitem.Id);

            Console.WriteLine("Relations: ");
            foreach (var relation in workitem.Relations)
            {

                if (relation.Rel == "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward")
                    Console.WriteLine(relation.Url);            

            }

            return workitem;
        }

    }
}
```